# convert sqlconnection to oledbconnection c#

Tags: c#

I am using C# to connect to my database with sqlconnection. 
But now I want to connect using OledbConnection.
I'm using this instruction:

```
 _dbSchemaInfo.Connection.ConnectionString = ViewModelLocator.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

and I have this Error:

> Un fournisseur OLE DB n'était pas spécifié dans ConnectionString. Par exemple, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

My ConnectionString:

> Data Source=MOHAMEDSADEK-PC\MSSQLSERVER12;Initial Catalog=TEST_LAUNCHER;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False

My question is "How Can I convert sqlconnection to OledbConnection ?

Comment: The error message says your connection string is wrong. Without your connection string we definitely can't tell you why it is wrong.

Comment: My connection work in other methode in the same programme. I thing I found it. I have to declare my connection as a DbConnection and instantiate it as either a OleDbConnection or a SqlConnection later.

Comment: My problem always exist !!

Comment: Without the relevant code we can't help. The syntax of OLEDB and SQL connection strings *is* different. You *can't* use a SQL Server connection string with an OleDBConnection class. Anyway, if you are using the abstract DbConnection class correctly, you *shouldn't* care whether an OLEDB or a SQL connection is created. Where is the code that creates the connection and *why* do you want to open an OleDbConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message and [this link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/), you need to set a Provider in your ConnectionString.

e.g. :

> Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MOHAMEDSADEK-PC\MSSQLSERVER12;Initial Catalog=TEST_LAUNCHER;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False

See more about connection providers with this links :

Provider Property (ADO) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675096(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope it will help